# SQL Server table name starting with # in user database, not in tempdb, not a temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, temporary-tables

Somehow, decades ago, a table got created in our database that starts with a `#`. It shows up in Object Explorer under the app's database, not in `tempdb`. For some reason, Azure won't import the database like this.

We can't drop it, rename it, or interact with it. I've tried *Delete* from Object Explorer, *Script Drop*, *Rename* from the GUI and none of them have worked.

We're on SQL 2008 R2.

```
drop table [*app*].[dbo]."#OBSOLETE";

Database name '*app*' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '#OBSOLETE', because it does not exist or you do not 
have permission.

exec sp_rename "dbo.#OBSOLETE", "dbo.obsolete"

Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 338
No item by the name of 'dbo.#OBSOLETE' could be found in the current database '*app*', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.
```

How do we kill this object so we can migrate this to Azure?

Comment: Try putting brackets around the table name, same response?

Comment: Can you try using the QUOTENAME function if @rvsc48's solution doesn't do it (although I think it will).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql

Comment: Brackets: same response.

Comment: You don't need a `.dbo` in the second part of the rename. [See here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/the-sp_rename-follies/) for why!

Comment: trying to use quotename within sp_rename doesn't work either: 
    exec sp_rename QUOTENAME('[app].[dbo].[#OBSOLETE]'), 'obsolete';
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near '[app].[dbo].[#OBSOLETE]'.

Comment: **1)** Have you tried dropping the object via Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)? **2)** If Object Explorer can't drop it, can you do a `SELECT * FROM sys.tables` and copy/paste the name into your query editor. It is possible that a non-printable character got in there, to the left of the `#`, and hence it is not seen as being a temp table or even `dbo.#OBSOLETE` since it might actually be `dbo.{hidden}#OBSOLETE`.

Comment: SSMS won't delete it either. Error 3701--does not exist or does not have permission. And I did try the copy/paste from Object Explorer, sys.tables, etc.

Comment: Please run the following query in the DB containing this table and paste the output into the question: `SELECT [name], CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), [name]) FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = N'#OBSOLETE';`. Thanks.

Comment: @thatitguy Why don't try `DROP TABLE [#OBSOLETE]` as suggested.

Comment: DROP TABLE #obsolete returns "Cannot drop the table '#obsolete', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." I'd rather not post the varbinary conversion because I've redacted table names, but it starts 0x23 as expected

Comment: @thatitguy I don't think you can even create a table in your database with `#` because it will auto-create in tempdb.

Comment: @thatitguy Ok, understood about not wanting to paste the VARBINARY output here. But I assume you mean that it starts with `0x2300..`. Also, did you check all of the other Code Points to make sure that they are all as expected?

Comment: varbinary matches. @Sami -- I'm assuming this table came from an earlier version of SQL Server. It shows it was created in 2002.

Comment: Have you tried: `EXEC sp_rename 'dbo."#OBSOLETE"', 'obsolete', 'object';` ? In the question you have the quotes around the schema and the object name. Here, I have a second set of quotes inside, around only the table name. And, you can't include the schema name on the destination name.

Comment: I would recommend trying to get a copy of the database back into SQL 2000 and then try to drop it or rename it, I feel like it may have been a defect in a previous version that allowed this table to be created - if so, the same defect should allow you to modify it.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky `Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (object) is wrong.`

Comment: Can you not just use permissions so the account doing the migration can't see it? Don't add the account to any database roles and grant whatever permissions are needed on every individual object except that problem one.

Comment: How big is the database?  If it's only a few GB or less it may be reasonable to just create a new DB and copy the tables to it...

Comment: `sp_rename` will never work https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lVjr.png

Comment: @MartinSmith They're using "extract data-tier application" which requires security_admin, database_owner, etc. I think that would bypass trying to restrict access.

Comment: yep looks like it from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application#Permissions

Comment: Another option (that I don't have time to test): **1)** Get the `object_id` of that table. **2)** Restart the instance in single-user mode. **3)** connect via Dedicated Admin Connection. **4)** In that DB, try something like `UPDATE sys.objects$ SET [name] =N'obsolete' WHERE [object_id] = {ye_olde_object_id}; {enter} GO {enter}`. Worth a shot..

Comment: @MartinSmith The application team found an option to exclude the table from the BACPAC, so they've worked around the issue. Still curious if there is a way to delete this table short of dropping the whole database.

Comment: @thatitguy Did you try the suggestion I made 2 comments above this one? The suggestion to edit the table directly in a Dedicated Admin Console connection?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Yes! I cloned the database to a development instance that I can take to single-user mode, and it let me change the name. Can you make that an answer?

Comment: If all fails you can move all remaining tables to a new database and drop the old one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given:

1. `sp_rename` uses object names instead of object IDs,
2. we cannot use the object name since it starts with a `#` and that is interpreted as having special meaning and is handled differently,
3. all other options have been exhausted

You should try editing the underlying system catalog table directly via a [Dedicated Admin Console (DAC) connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators):

1. Get the `object_id` of that table.
2. Restart the instance in Single-User mode. This is to be able to directly update the system tables (i.e. not a requirement for using the DAC connection).
3. Connect via Dedicated Admin Console connection. You can do this in a SQLCMD interactive session by running the following in a Command Prompt window:

   ```
   C:\> SQLCMD -A -E
   ```

   or, connect directly to the DB using:

   ```
   C:\> SQLCMD -A -E -d {database_name}
   ```
4. In that DB, try something like the following:

   ```sql
   UPDATE sys.objects$ {enter}
   SET [name] = N'obsolete' {enter}
   WHERE [object_id] = {ye_olde_object_id}; {enter}
   GO {enter}
   ```

   It won't execute the statement until you put in the `GO {enter}`.

**Please be cautious when directly editing system catalog tables, and do not get too comfortable with the idea of doing it. This is something that should be done *only* if there is absolutely no other way of fixing a problem (such as the case here).** There are probably several reasons to avoid making direct edits, but the two that initially come to mind are:

- Much like the data-models that we create, there are likely rules and workflows for how things work that we are unaware of (e.g. denormalization, "business" rules governing the state of data across various tables, etc)
- Quite likely making direct edits voids Microsoft's responsibility to assist you if you run into problems and have a support contract (I have not seen the terms of the Support agreement(s), but I have a hard time believing that such language would not be in there)

  [@Paul Randal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/94938/) confirmed in a comment on a [related answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/192941/30859) of mine: "manually editing a system table irrevocably sets a flag in the boot page of the database that marks your database as having been edited in this way, and CSS might decide to not help you if you subsequently have problems with that database."

Comment: I like the answer, but maybe it's worth adding a sentence as to why this is so dangerous to do?

Comment: @JoeObbish Thanks, and good suggestion. I will try to add something tomorrow.

Comment: @JoeObbish I just added something. Is that sufficient?